# How use a canonical link tag in a dynamic page?

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, duplicate-content, canonical-url, dynamic

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/category/subcategory/example-product/product-id" />
```

I have a whole bunch of query string URLs (company products) that I have rewritten to friendly ones (such as that indicated above). At present, seems search engines are still seeing both versions, so I thought perhaps I should add the canonical tag to my preferred URL.

Incredibly, days and days of trolling god-knows-what web development resources on the internet has not clearly answered the question of "how" for me. Hoping someone here can help.

For the record, I am utilizing a single file (*products1.php*) to populate all of my products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*products1.php* simply needs to output the canonical link in the head section of the page.  Presumably it knows the information needed to build your friendly URL:

- category
- subcategory
- product name
- product id

Then the canonical tag appears in *both* the page for the friendly URL and the page for the parameterized URL.   That is fine. [Google says that a canonical link that points to the current page would be OK](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical.html).

Comment: So then I would render the canonical link in the tag as: "http://www.example.com/...""??

Comment: You would use the full friendly URL including http and the hostname

Comment: But there's dozens of friendly URL's because I have dozens of products. I'm obviously dense, can you clarify?

Comment: Since the page is dynamic the script would build the matching canonical url for the current product